# Yii2 app in a subdirectory of a Wordpress website: cannot enable pretty urls

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, apache2

I’m trying to deploy a basic webapp on a shared environment where Wordpress is on the root. The Yii2 app is in /subfolder.

I’m following [this guide](https://devreadwrite.com/posts/htaccess-for-yii-2-basic). In root’s .htaccess I added:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/web
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]

    RewriteBase /subfolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /web/index.php
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But with these rules added all Wordpress’ pages are handled (or attempted) through Yii, so this breaks the blog installation. It’s the first block of rules capturing all the pages, but I don’t understand why as the two `RewriteCond` should intercept only the Yii app URIs. I checked mod_rewrite docs but couldn’t understand what’s wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To clarify, your Yii2 app URLs include the `/subfolder`? `/web` is in the root, outside of `/subfolder`? Although you seem to switch between `/subfolder` and `/web`?

Comment: Yii2 app is in `/subfolder`. Yii2 basic app has all the *public* stuff in `web/`, so the main Yii2 `index.php` is `/subfolder/web/index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteBase /subfolder
> ```

You cannot set multiple `RewriteBase` directives in the same `.htaccess` file. The *last* instance "wins" and controls the entire file. So, in the `.htaccess` file you posted, `RewriteBase /` set in the WordPress code block, is what is actually set for the file.

However, none of the directives actually make use of the `RewriteBase` directive anyway - so none of the `RewriteBase` directives are actually doing anything. The `RewriteBase` directive only applies where you have set a *relative* path (not starting with a *slash*) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

> but I don’t understand why as the two RewriteCond should intercept only the Yii app URIs.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/web
> RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
> ```

Presumably it's these two `RewriteCond` directives you are referring to... in which case these two *conditions* aren't really doing anything. `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows, so it only applies to the directive that rewrites your `assets`.

However, this `RewriteRule` is matching `/assets` in the document root, not `/subfolder/assets`, which is presumably the requirement - so these rules will fail to match.

> But with these rules added all Wordpress’ pages are handled (or attempted) through Yii, so this breaks the blog installation.

The rules will certainly "break the blog installation", however, they don't appear to get as far as handling the request "through Yii". There's nothing that actually rewrites the request to `/subfolder`. However, the following directive unconditionally rewrites *everything* to the `/web` directory in the document root (which presumably does not exist) - so this will certainly "break" all the WordPress URLs.

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
> ```

In fact, I would have expected this to have created a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error response)?! Unless you have a subdirectory `/web` off the document root which also contains an `.htaccess` file containing mod_rewrite directives? But that seems unlikely, since the `/web` directory should be inside the `/subfolder` directory?

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(subfolder)/(assets|css|js|images)/(.*) $1/web/$2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder)/((?!web).*) $1/web/$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^subfolder/web/index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(subfolder)/. $1/web/index.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper. Or the `RewriteBase` directive.

### Alternatively

However, it would be preferable to move these directives into their own `.htaccess` file in the root of the project, ie. `/subfolder/.htaccess` - which I believe is what the linked "guide" is suggesting. This keeps the two projects entirely separate. And avoids having to explicitly include the `/subfolder` in the directives.

In addition, creating a another `.htaccess` file in the `web` subdirectory, ie. `/subfolder/web/.htaccess`. This is again, suggested in the linked "guide". However, this also negates the need for the additional directives to route the request in the parent `.htaccess` file.

For example, putting these changes together, the `/.htaccess` file in the document root should only have the WordPress directives. And then...

#### `/subfolder/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?:assets|css|js|images)/.*) web/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!web).*) web/$1 [L]
```

#### `/subfolder/web/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Again, no need for the `RewriteBase` directive here - in fact, using `RewriteBase` here arguably complicates things. When in the `/subfolder/web/.htaccess` file, all relative URL-paths are relative to that directory.

So, requesting `/subfolder/foo` gets internally rewritten by the `/subfolder/.htaccess` file to `/subfolder/web/foo`. Which is then caught by the `/subfolder/web/.htaccess` file (preventing a rewrite loop) and internally rewritten to `/subfolder/web/index.php` (providing `foo` does not exist as a physical file).

Comment: Thank you very much, I was missing a lot of htaccess knowledge. It's 99% perfect, but I missed a bit so you couldn't know: Yii2 app is server via `web/index.php`, the purpose of the linked guide is to hide that path so the app is accessible on the *root* path. With your config when I enable the *baseUrl* config option in Yii it won't load css|js assets anymore, the html source is correct but when I try accessing a CSS o JS file I get a 301 redirect to the path without file name

Comment: I cannot figure out where does the redirect come from. I disabled WP's htaccess but it still happens, I checked Yii app and it's not processed by that. Changing the first rule to `RewriteRule ^((assets|css|js|images)/.*) web/$1 [L]` seems to solve

Comment: Sorry, yes, the regex alternation needs the internal brackets, otherwise it's `assets` or `css` or `js` or `images/.*` and you'd lose the filename on _assets_, _css_ and _js_ - I'd previously changed that code and forgot to add them in! I've updated my answer (and made it a non-capturing group). "the purpose of the linked guide is to hide that path" - Just to clarify, it hides `web` and `web/index.php`, it doesn't hide `/subfolder` (that would be impossible).

Comment: "I cannot figure out where does the redirect come from." - The 301 redirect would have been triggered by mod_dir (it's not in the code). The incorrect regex would have resulted in a rewrite to `web/assets` (or `web/css` or `web/js`) and since `assets` (and `css` and `js`) are physical directories, mod_dir would have issued a 301 redirect to append (fix) the trailing slash (exposing the `web` directory). This is default Apache behaviour.